# Handling Concurrent Service Calls in ROS 2 Action Server Callback

Tags: ros2, multithreading, foxy

I'm developing a ROS 2 application and facing challenges with concurrent service calls within an action server callback. My get_all_ras_poses_concurrent function retrieves the current poses of all RAS nodes through sequential service calls. It works as expected independently, but causes issues when invoked within the divide_roi_callback of an action server.

Here's the get_all_ras_poses_concurrent function:

```
def get_all_ras_poses_concurrent(self) -> List[List[float]]:
        all_pose_xy = []
        for ras_id, client in self.ras_pose_clients.items():
            request = GetRASPose.Request()
            request.is_agent=True
            future = client.call_async(request)
            rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)
            if future.result() is not None:
                pose = future.result().ras_pose.pose.position
                # Extracting x, y coordinates and rounding them to two decimal places
                x, y = round(pose[1], 2), round(pose[2], 2)
                all_pose_xy.append([x, y])
            else:
                self.get_logger().error(f"Failed to get pose for ras_id: {ras_id}")

        return all_pose_xy
```

And the divide_roi_callback where it's called:

```
def divide_roi_callback(self, goal_handle) -> action.ShareRoi.Result:
   # ... [other parts of the function]
   uav_positions = self.get_all_ras_poses_concurrent()[:ras_number]
   # ... [rest of the function]
```

Additionally, here's the part of my code where the action server is defined:

```
self.share_roi_action = ActionServer(
   self,
   action.ShareRoi,
   "navigation/action/share_roi",
   handle_accepted_callback=self.handle_accepted_callback,
   execute_callback=self.divide_roi_callback,
   # ... [remaining parameters]
)
```

And the main function where the node and executor are set up:

```
def main(args=None) -> None:
   rclpy.init(args=args)
   navigation_server = NavigationServer()
   executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
   executor.add_node(navigation_server)
   # ... [try-except block and shutdown]
```

When get_all_ras_poses_concurrent is called within the action server callback, it disrupts the normal execution of other callbacks. I'm trying to understand the cause of this issue and how to handle concurrent service calls effectively in this context. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit short of time to write a manifesto, but if you join the Nav2 Working Group meeting tomorrow, I can explain it.